# Does specifying STRICT on a PostgreSQL trigger procedure do anything?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, trigger, functions

Does specifying `CALLED ON NULL INPUT`, `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` or `STRICT` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) on a trigger procedure in PostgreSQL do anything?

Since a trigger procedure must be declared as a function with no arguments (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html), I doubt it has any effect but I cannot find a definite answer on this one.